Confusion in asking question either in the past or present tenses
I have read the following sentence:

If I brought the doughnuts into my class, could you refrain from eating them?

Question: I understand the meaning of this sentence. However, I don't know why it is written in the past tense. Why can't it be in the present tense?

If I bring doughnuts into my class, can you refrain from eating them?


What's actually meant is "If I were to bring doughnuts into my class, could you refrain from eating them?" But in casual language we often replace conditionals like that with the past tense.

Conditionals in Interrogative form.
OP's two interrogative sentences are:

1.If I brought the doughnuts into my class, could you refrain from eating them?
2.If I bring doughnuts into my class, can you refrain from eating them?

These sentences are Conditional sentences (or questions) in interrogative form.
When we convert a conditional statement to a question, we modify the main clause but leave the if clause intact.
(For detail explanation  Proper way to build interogative conditionals)
If you convert these interrogative sentences into statements:
1..If I brought the doughnuts into my class,  you couldn't/ wouldn't refrain from eating them.
This sentence is a Second Conditional sentence. It is a hypothetical or imaginary situation. It is unlikely to happen.
Suppose the speaker is a child. He doesn't carry doughnuts in his lunch box because he knows it would be all eaten by his classmates.
2..If I bring doughnuts into my class, you cannot refrain from eating them..
This sentence is in Zero conditional form
We use the zero conditional to talk about things that are generally true.

Thanks, it helped.

This is an example of a common 'irrealis' form of words in a sentence with conditional mood. It looks like the speaker is using the past tense, but in fact it has no tense at all when used in this hypothetical, conditional way.
Hypothetical situations can be extremely flexible in terms of whether they use active verbs or words like 'could', 'should', 'might', 'would' which can look like past tense verbs, but are being used as tenseless modals.
I wrote another answer here which tried to illustrate just how varied irrealis constructions can be, while meaning (to all intents and purposes) the same thing.
Your example sentence is perfectly good English, but there is nothing 'past' about it. In fact it is discussing a hypothetical situation that might happen in the future if certain conditions are met.

Thanks, it helped.
